# populate a field with the result of subtracting two other fields

Tags: django

i have the following model

```
class FeeModel(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    total_fee=models.IntegerField(default=100000)
    paid_fee=models.IntegerField()
    remaining_fee=models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

i need the remaining_fee to be filled by the result of (total_fee - paid_fee). How would i do that?

Comment: If the solution below works for you, consider accepting the answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in numerous ways and places.  A pre_save signal is one approach.

(In models.py, below your FeeModel class)

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(pre_save, sender=FeeModel)
def set_remaining_fee(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    instance.remaining_fee = (instance.total_fee - instance.paid_fee)
```

How this works: A user enters the values for `total_fee` and `paid_fee` into a form.  Upon submit and just before save(), the signal calculates the difference and applies it to the `remaining_fee` field.  Note that this will run every time the model instance is saved.